# Generate multiple reports from SSRS 2012 subscription into one ZIP file to email

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS 2012 report and subscription set up where it checks a database every 15 minutes for the arrival of a new file, which contains order info for potentially dozens of orders.  Right now during my testing it sends me an emailed report for each order in that file and this morning I received 38 emails, each with a spreadsheet for each of the different orders.

Is it possible to send all orders from a submitted file in one emailed Zip file? I will have to change the subscription to rename each file with its own particular order# in the filename but it's the process of grouping them into one Zip file to email that's giving me trouble.

Comment: Good day, Please remove the tag tsql as this question has nothing to do with queries (transact sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to send all orders from a submitted file in one emailed Zip file?

#### Option 1:

When you configure the Report Delivery Option select the option "Windows File Share" instead of "Email"

Now all options are open for you. (1) The files will be added to the shared folder. (2) You can collect the files and every X time that you want, execute a third party application like 7zip or the built-in zip app and build your package. (3) Using the same script send the email.

Note: You can create "[Azure file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction)" and configure the file as local shared folder. Configure the Report Delivery to Store the files in that shared folder.